# Defining TypeScript function taking object with unspecified number of keys

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have a function that takes an object as an input and returns an object as well. I would like to define it such that it can have any number of keys in the input or returned object.

Right now, I define it like this:

```
const myFunc: ({}) => ({})
```

Is there a good way to write it to avoid any type errors while also using the advantages that TS provides?

Comment: `Record<string, any>`

Comment: It would be useful if you provide more details about a function. What kind of transformation thi function does with argument?

Answer (score 2):

You can use TypeScript's [`Record<K, V>`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#recordkeys-type) type to specify an object with arbitrary keys of type `K` and values of type `V`:

```js
type MyObj = Record<string, any>;
```

Keys must be strings, numbers, or symbols, but values can be any type you specify. Your function would then become:

```js
const myFunc = (obj: Record<???, ???>): Record<???, ???> => { /* ... */ };
```

Comment: It's perfectly valid to have things that aren't num/symbol/string as keys.  `let func = () => 1` and `{func: 2}` is a valid object.

Comment: @nlta did you mean as a computed property like `{ [func]: 2 }`? Even so, all non-string keys aside from symbols are stringified and do not remain objects. TypeScript will not allow anything aside from string, number, or symbol as a key in its Record type, or in its object literal type e.g. `type Foo = { [index: ???]: ??? }`.

Comment: Oh right you are! I didn't realize it was stringified.